# In Kicad 5.1, how do you access the Net Class Editor

Tags: kicad

In Version 5.0, you accessed from the Setup Menu.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to access this at all in version 5.1.  The is no Setup menu.

Perplexed.
-Jim

Answer (score 4):

File → Board Setup → Design rules → Net Classes